# What's the use of return a Callable result in a controller return?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Someone like to use Callable to build the return value of the controller due to Spring mvc
such as:

```
    @RestController
    public class TController{
         @GetMappint("helloWorld")
         public Callable<String> demo(){
             return new Callable<String>() {
                 @Override
                 public String call() throws Exception {
                     //do sth.
                    return "hello world";
                 }
             };
         }    
    }
```

I think it is Useless and equivalent to this example：

```
 @RestController
    public class TController{
         @GetMappint("helloWorld")
         public String demo(){
             //do sth.
            return "hello world";
         }    
    }
```

it is that sure?

Answer (score 1):

No, basically you're wrong.

There is a use case for returning `Callable<String>`. Lets say the service that you'll call from the controller runs for a long time. During this time, in a traditional model of thread-per-request, the tomcat thread that is meant to server connections will be stuck.

So starting with servlet 3.0 there is a way to run things asynchronously, and this is the way to do it in spring MVC:
In fact, returning callable from controller method instructs Spring MVC to invoke the task defined in the Callable in a different thread.

You might find [this article](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/07/understanding-callable-and-spring-deferredresult.html) relevant to your quesion

Comment: Thanks a lot,I think I didn't understand Servlet Threading Model well before.